# Shortcode output adding <br /> after new line

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to create a shortcode to add a CSS style attribute to a page. I added the following code to my theme's functions.php.

```
function add_style( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<style>' . $content . '</style>';
}
add_shortcode( 'style', 'add_style' );
```

In the editor of the page I used it as:

```
[style]
.image-main{
  border:5px solid lightblue;
}
[/style]
```

On the rendered page it outputs to:

```
<style>
<br />
.image-main{<br />
  border:5px solid lightblue;<br />
}<br />

</style>
```

How can I set up the shortcode to remove the `<br />` when I have multi-line content?

Comment: Post the code behind the shortcode.

Comment: How can I do that? Just not use the closing [/style]?

Comment: I'm asking if you can post the PHP you wrote that handles the custom shortcode in your question.

Comment: do you know how to write jQuery?

Comment: I added the PHP. And yes, I know how to write jQuery.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The br tag gets inserted because of the default order in which WordPress processes your content – wpautop (the function which converts line breaks to p or br tags) is run before the shortcodes are processed.

**The Solution:**

Change the execution priority of wpautop so that it executes after the shotcodes are processed instead of before. Add this in your functions.php file:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);
```

Now there will be no extra p or br tags added inside your shortcode block. In fact there will not be any automatic conversion of line breaks to p and/or br tags at all. So if you want the legitimate line breaks to convert to p and br tags, you will need to run wpautop from inside your shortcode function, e.g.:

```
function bio_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
   $content = wpautop(trim($content));
   return '<div class="bio">' . $content . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode('bio', 'bio_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found to my problem was to replace remove `"<br /r>"` using `str_replace();`

```
function add_style( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $pure_content = str_replace("<br />","",$content);
    return '<style>' . $pure_content . '</style>';
}
add_shortcode( 'style', 'add_style' );
```